# How to add LinkedIn's Burrow to a Docker Compose?

Tags: docker-compose, dockerhub, kafka

It appears `LinkedIn` doesn't have an official Burrow docker image on Docker Hub, but there are others who have forked it.

However, I can't find any examples of how to add any of them to a docker compose file that spins up ZK and Kafka something like [this](https://github.com/simplesteph/kafka-stack-docker-compose/blob/master/full-stack.yml).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

This is the example I was looking for: https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow/blob/master/docker-compose.yml